# make python3.3 installation the default installation

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I've just installed manually python3.3 sources on the directory : `/opt/python3.3` on my laptop which contains python2.6 as default installation.
But now i need to make the python3.3 as the default one and execute some commands as it said in this post : [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084416/tkinter-module-not-found-on-ubuntu)

how can i do that ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you have installed from source, you are pretty much on your own.

You can do something like creating `~/bin/python` symlink from your home directory to `/opt/python-3.3/bin/python`, and then adding `$HOME/bin` to `PATH` in your `.bashrc`.

Or, you can add `/opt/python-3.3/bin` to your `PATH` instead.

But, in both of these cases, you will not be able to use standard package manager to install Python extensions - these are only provided for Python installed as standard Ubuntu package.

Comment: thank you. I installed it from source because when I try to execute : `sudo apt-get install python3.1` it gives me _404  Not Found [IP : 91.189.91.13 80]_

Comment: I assume that you have Ubuntu 12.10. Note that Ubuntu 12.10 has Python 3.2.3 by default - is this not good enough for you already? But it is called `python3` (`python` points to Python 2.7). Maybe this is the reason why does not want to go down to 3.1.

Comment: no, I only have ubuntu 10.10

Comment: you can try adding backports repo to get some of the newer packages. But, 10.10 was not LTS, and is already removed from official repository list. You may try using [Lucid python3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/python/python3-all), but this is going to be hit or miss. You might want to actually upgrade your Ubuntu...